# Prepositions with fields (agricultural)

Tags: prepositions

According to the Longman dictionay I use, you ought to say "in the fields", but I'm pretty sure I've come across "on the fields" before. Is it possible to use it? And if so, does it imply a change in meaning?

I'm adding some sentences for example as requested:
- Someone works in/on the fields.
- Someone is in/on the fields.

Comment: Both phrases are used; which one to choose depends on context.  Please add more context to your question, for example by writing some complete sentences containing the phrases in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are certainly possible.  Typically *in the fields* is used to indicate something akin to *within the borders of the fields*.  However, *on the fields* usually is trying to indicate something closer to *on top of the fields*.

For example, you might say a farmer is

> driving in the fields
>
> spreading fertilizer on the fields